# Fatal error in ../../webrtc/modules/utility/source/jvm_android.cc

Tags: webrtc, twilio, twilio-api, apprtcdemo, apprtc

We are facing one issue related to Twilio Programmable SDK & AppRTC version 57 for Android. As we have integrated both in existing Android application. You can have a look at the below link for your reference on Gradle dependencies and log cat crash logs.

Logcat crash logs -

```
E/rtc: #
   # Fatal error in ../../webrtc/modules/utility/source/jvm_android.cc, line 233
   # last system error: 88
   # Check failed: !g_jvm
   # 
   #
08-01 16:54:30.975 9534-9534/? A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9534
```

#### Twilio Programmable Video SDK

While we use Twilio Programmable multi-party video call, it's get crashed for the first time and when we perform same Twilio Programmable multi-party video call for the second time, it's get connected but AppRTC P2P video call gets crashed.

#### AppRTC

While we use AppRTC P2P video call, first it gets crashed and when we perform same AppRTC P2P video call for the second time, it's get connected but Twilio Multiparty call gets crashed.

As we need both AppRTC & Twilio Programmable Video SDK in our existing project.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Perform AppRTC P2P/Twilio Video call.
2. When the video call is connected, app crashes.
3. Perform Twilio/AppRTC P2P Video call.
4. When the video call is connected, app crashes.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to make simultaneous calls using Twilio Video and AppRTC? Or calls between the two?

Comment: For multi-party make use of Twilio video SDK and for peer to peer we make use of AppRTC, both SDK's work independently but whenever we make peer to peer call after Twilio multiparty call the app is crashing.

Comment: Did you know that Twilio Video supports peer to peer conversations too? I've asked the team about why this might not be working, but it could just be easier to use one tool for the communication rather than two.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe you've been in contact with Twilio support regarding this issue. I just thought I'd update this publicly too.

Currently, Twilio Video Android SDK is not side-by-side compatible with AppRTC. There is likely to be work in the future to make this possible, but for now it won't work.